# I want to import Text file(CSV) data to Azure SQL by using logic-App

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service, azure-logic-apps, azure-files

I tried using HTTP request I am able to send the data from HTTP request to azure SQL but I am manually Send the data through postman but that is not my requirement

**Requirement**:I need to use a **scheduler** and a particular time the data from the text file  need to be read and to be stored into Azure-SqlDB

if you have any resource or examples please let me know

Comment: What is the text file stored?

Comment: A text file can contain comma-separated values

Comment: Sorry, I meant to ask where is the text file stored?

Comment: You should elaborate your question. And spend time on researching solutions. Currently its not detailed enough to be answered effectively.

Comment: Hi @KarthikKasula If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can mark it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About how import Text file(CSV) data to Azure SQL by using logic-App, you could reference this tutorial: [Quick, easy and cheap way to automate data loading from CSV file into Azure SQL](https://marczak.io/posts/azure-loading-csv-to-sql/):

- Check out how to leverage Azure Blob Storage and Logic Apps for
  simple scenario of data loading from CSV into Azure SQL in less than
  30 minutes and with almost no coding.
- About any developer out there at some point or another had to
  automate ETL process for data loading. This article will present a
  fast and convinient way to create data loading workflow for CSVs
  using Azure SQL and blob storage.

It also introduced other ways you could reference:

1. How import Text file(CSV) data to Azure SQL by using Data Factory.
2. How import Text file(CSV) data from Blob stroage to Azure SQL by
       using T-SQL.

You also could reference:

1. [Upload Flat File on Azure SQL Database using Azure Logic App](https://pellitterisbiztalkblog.wordpress.com/2016/11/14/upload-flat-file-on-azure-sql-database-using-azure-logic-app/)
2. [Using Azure Logic Apps to Import CSV to SQL Server](http://blogs.recneps.org/post/Using-Azure-Logic-Apps-to-Import-CSV-to-SQL-Server)

I'm agree with @Mandar Dharmadhikari, Logic app is not the best way to do it.

If your csv file with large data, I also suggest you to use Data Factory，when the copy active pipeline created, you could [trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-pipeline-execution-triggers) the pipeline executing in schedule.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you yo use Azure Data Factory as it is more suited to the task that you want to perform. Following post gives the idea on how to move csv  data fo SQL.

http://normalian.hatenablog.com/entry/2017/09/04/233320